# Type complex vs two level

Tags: multilevel-analysis, mplus

I am conducting a cfa (two level, with meaning of level 2;it is staff rating organizations and we care about organizations).

My question is what is the difference is in mplus between type=complex (mlr with sandwich) and type=twolevel if mlr is selected as an estimator with no covariates in the model?

These should be the same corrct?

Answer (score 1):

If you care about the organizations (the clusters), then use `type=twolevel` and estimate a within and a between part of your model.

If you were not concerned about the clustering level but wanted to control for within-cluster correlation (you should do that), you would use `type=complex` to make Mplus use a sandwich estimator.

These two solutions are different in that they will estimate different models (two-level vs single level), and you can expect that they will produce different results for the within part (which would be the only part estimated if you use `type=complex` model).